# Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'MessageChain' type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Всем привет, столкнулся с такой проблемой, хотел заимплементировать максимально несвязанную цепь обязаностей через Spring. Идея заключалась в том, чтобы в конфигурации передавать абстрактный класс и автоматически привязывать следующую цепь, если она существует, если её нет, чтобы просто передавалось значение null.

Столкнулся с проблемой - `Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'MessageChain' type.`

[image: конфиг]

Как видно на скриншоте, в первом случае, spring просит квалифицировать бин либо указать его явно, как я сделал с `secondChain`.

Вопрос следующий, выйдет ли через спринг сделать настолько неявную привязку? Мне это нужно для того, чтобы при создании новой цепочки не прописывать её в предыдущей а просто дописать в конфиг. Если нет, подскажите пожалуйста возможные способы решения этой проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так, путём махинаций и различных тестов я нашёл оптимальное решение для своего случая,прилагаю скриншот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мы можем создать очередь и тянуть из неё элементы, метод `poll()`
позволит нам не словить нал поинтер а просто вставить налл, если в очереди нету элементов нашей цепи, что будет актуально для первой цепи, так как в очереди не будет элементов. В дальнейшем с помощью метода `element()` мы сможем вытянуть первую цепочку для конфигурации остальных модулей.

Comment: Проблема в том что спринг не гарантирует что он вызовет методы в определенном порядке. То есть теоретически здесь может быть как SecondChain(GreetingMessageChain) так и наоборот GreetingMessageChain(SecondChain)

Comment: В этом и задумка, я как раз стремился к тому, чтобы вызывать методы в любом порядке и чтобы последний вызванный ссылался на null

Comment: Просто суть цепочки в том, что каждая цепь автономна и порядок их очереди не важен.

Comment: тогда зачем вообще собирать их в цепочки?

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, тебе нужно иметь несколько реализаций одного интерфейса в контекте.

Для этого ты можешь объявить несколько компонентов одного типа (MessageChain)

```
@Bean
public static MessageChain messageChain1(){...}
@Bean
public static MessageChain messageChain2(){...}
@Bean
public static MessageChain messageChain3(){...}
```

, а затем инжектить их сразу списком.

```
@Autowired
private List<MessageChain> messageChains;
```

Я вижу, что тебе нужно, чтобы chain-ы были в определенном порядке. Для этого ты можешь отнаследовать `MessageChain` от интерфейса [`Ordered`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html). Тогда Spring автоматически отсортирует все chain-ы по значению метода getOrder()

Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, порядок мне не важен, важно лишь то, чтобы в конечном итоге каждый  чейн ссылался на следующий а последний на налл, какой именно будет последним или первым или вторым, для меня не важно)
Но вот инжект списка - это интересно, не могли бы вы описать подробнее?

Comment: Концепция такова, что не важен порядок, важно только, чтобы каждый чейн ссылался на другой чейн а последний чейн имел ссылку на следующий чейн равную null

Comment: тогда ты можешь сразу собрать весь чейн сразу (всю цепочку) в одном методе, а вернуть только его "голову".

Comment: А что List уже не является Ordered?

Comment: Суть в том, чтобы не собирать как раз таки всё в одном методе, так как это по сути ничего не изменит, цепь собираю в отдельном конфиге. Ведь при сборке в методе, мне всё равно нужно будет указать, что цепь 2 ссылается на цепь 3 и тд. Я в свою очередь хочу изберать этого. Хочу сделать что-то например 2 цепь ссылается на любую цепь, если ещё существуют цепи, которые не приписаны ни к какой цепи, как-то так.